# How do I read the next line then call a function?

Tags: c

I have a simple problem where I am supposed to read (line by line) from a text file and organize the input into separate arrays for digits/symbols/uppercase/lowercase. I created 2 functions, one that gets characters and stores them into their respected arrays, and another which sorts them (bubble sort). My problem is that I cannot figure out how to call the two functions for every new line.

Comment: Just stop the loop on `\n`, and add another loop till `EOF` so that all lines get read.

Comment: So have the first while loop end on \n, and another inside the first loop till EOF?

Comment: No, wrap all that you have in another loop till EOF and change the present loop condition to `'\n'` and `EOF` (since a line may end by `EOF` or by `\n`). BTW, why remove the code?

Answer (score 1):

```
int main()
{
     char line[256]= "";

     while (fgets(line, sizeof(line)-1, stdin)!=NULL) {
         bubbleSort(line, strlen(line));
     }
```

See also this [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) for an example how to read line by line from a file.

Or char by char:

```
int idx= 0;
char line[256];

while((c=getchar()) != EOF){    
    if(c != '\n'){
        line[idx]= c;  // store char by char in line at next pos
        idx++;
    }
    else {  // at \n pass the line and length to bubbleSort
        bubbleSort(line, idx);
        idx= 0;
    }
```

}

Comment: You assume that a line can not be longer than 256 chars, which is not good. There was no such limitation in the original program. In fact, you are solving another problem.

Comment: @Aneri: It did look pretty much like the same problem as long as the dude had input samples and his sample code still shown in the question.

Comment: He had to distinguish digits, lowercase and uppercase chars, plus he skipped duplicates.

Comment: Quote: " My problem is that I cannot figure out how to call the two functions for every new line."

Comment: Yes, but I assume he wanted to run _his_ processing over each line, not the entire input. I think that simply adding a condition on `'\n'` and another external loop would have solved the problem.